# Selenium works locally, but can't click on a link on travis

Tags: selenium

I have the exact same version of selenium (2.53.6) and firefox (43.0) on a local virtualbox with Ubuntu trusty, and a trusty image on travis.

The HTML code is trivial

```
<div>
    <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-close fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Close</a><br>
</div>
```

The test code is trivial as well

```
def test_start_stop_container(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/hub/login")
    driver.find_element_by_id("username_input").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("username_input").send_keys("test")
    driver.find_element_by_id("password_input").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("password_input").send_keys("test")
    driver.find_element_by_id("login_submit").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("action").click()
    self.wait_for(lambda: "noVNC" == driver.title)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i").click()   # << this here.
    self.wait_for(lambda: "noVNC" != driver.title)
    driver.find_element_by_name("action").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@name='action'])[2]").click()
    self.wait_for(
        lambda: "Start" == driver.find_element_by_name("action").text)
    driver.find_element_by_id("logout").click()
```

In both cases I use Xvfb, but only on Travis the click is not working. No exception happens. It just seems like the operation is not performed. I recorded the session on Xvfb using some ffmpeg magic, and what I see is that the link highlights in blue (which is the hover color) but then the link is not clicked.

[This video shows the exact operation (starts around 20 sec mark)](https://transfer.sh/wz4EH/video.mp4)

Does anybody have an idea of what the problem could be, or if there's something I can do to debug it?

Comment: Are you talking about this line `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i").click()`??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur yes. That's actually one option. I also tried to select on the Close label, but the result is the same.

Comment: Did you tried using this `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Close").click()` or `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Close").click()`???

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I tried the first one (it actually was that one first, and I replaced with an xpath selector in desperation, which still works on my linux vbox). I'll try the second one. One sec.

Comment: If both results are same, you could consider this option as well using `execute_script()` to perform click `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", driver.find_element_by_link_text("Close"))`..

Comment: I tried with the find_element_by_partial_link_text. Still timeout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121867/discussion-between-stefano-borini-and-saurabh-gaur).

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Please post an answer with the driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", driver.find_element_by_link_text("Close")). entry. I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes off course, actually some time selenium click method of WebElement doesn't perform click due to some designing issue of the element or other issues in this case here is an alternative solution provided by selenium to execute piece of JavaScript to perform further events on the element thanks..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually some time `click()` method of `WebElement` doesn't work as expected due to some designing issue of the element or other issues. So in this case, here is an alternate solution provided by selenium to execute piece of `JavaScript` to perform further events on the element.

So can use `execute_script()` instead to perform click here as below :-

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", driver.find_element_by_link_text("Close"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath to identify the href - `"//a[contains(text(),'Close')]"`